# How to compute Cohen's d when provided percent difference and standard deviation?

Tags: effect-size, cohens-d

I am trying to compute Cohen's d from a published paper. M1 and M2 were provided as percent differences (the average difference in scores from t1 to t2 for an experimental group and then a control group). SD was provided.

M1=40.50%, SD1= 3.40    M2=6.89, SD2=5.78

Am I able to compute cohen's d by transforming these percentages or is more information required? If so, how do I compute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, the formula for *Cohen's d* is $d = \frac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2}{\hat{\sigma}}$ but there are different definitions for the pooled standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d). The pooled standard deviation can be defined with $\sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)*s_1^2 + (n_2-1)*s_2^2}{n_1+n_2}}$, for example. As you can see, you will need information on the sample sizes in order to calculate *Cohen's d*. Thus, to my understandig you can not calculate *Cohen's d*  with the provided information.

Besides, if your data can not exceed a range, i.e. if for logical reasons there can not be more than 100% or less than 0%, I wouldn't know how to calculate the confidence intervalls for your estimate because the range restriction changes the distribution of the mean differences.